# What is wrong with this JSON string?

Tags: json

I keep getting `NULL` when i do `$data = json_decode($data);` . To encode it in JS I use `var data = JSON.stringify( my_obj );` What is wrong with this JSON string?

```
 'guide' => string (1583) "[{\"instructions\":[\"sdasda\"],\"media\":[{\"id\":95,\"titl …"
```

**EDIT:**

I am adding the entire string as requested:

```
[{\"instructions\":[\"sdasda\"],\"media\":[{\"id\":95,\"title\":\"item4_1444\",\"filename\":\"item4_1444.jpg\",\"url\":\"http://localhost:8888/sandbox/content/uploads/2014/08/item4_1444.jpg\",\"link\":\"http://localhost:8888/sandbox/example/change-phone-home-button/item4_1444/\",\"alt\":\"\",\"author\":\"1\",\"description\":\"\",\"caption\":\"\",\"name\":\"item4_1444\",\"status\":\"inherit\",\"uploadedTo\":86,\"date\":\"2014-08-24T16:39:15.000Z\",\"modified\":\"2014-08-24T16:39:15.000Z\",\"menuOrder\":0,\"mime\":\"image/jpeg\",\"type\":\"image\",\"subtype\":\"jpeg\",\"icon\":\"http://localhost:8888/sandbox/includes/images/media/default.png\",\"dateFormatted\":\"24/08/2014\",\"nonces\":{\"update\":\"46bbaaed37\",\"delete\":\"bcda3390c5\",\"edit\":\"ea35506ec2\"},\"editLink\":\"http://localhost:8888/sandbox/admin/post.php?post=95&action=edit\",\"sizes\":{\"thumbnail\":{\"height\":150,\"width\":150,\"url\":\"http://localhost:8888/sandbox/content/uploads/2014/08/item4_1444-150x150.jpg\",\"orientation\":\"landscape\"},\"medium\":{\"height\":300,\"width\":200,\"url\":\"http://localhost:8888/sandbox/content/uploads/2014/08/item4_1444-200x300.jpg\",\"orientation\":\"portrait\"},\"full\":{\"url\":\"http://localhost:8888/sandbox/content/uploads/2014/08/item4_1444.jpg\",\"height\":960,\"width\":640,\"orientation\":\"portrait\"}},\"height\":960,\"width\":640,\"orientation\":\"portrait\",\"compat\":{\"item\":\"\",\"meta\":\"\"},\"html_id\":\"ge-step-image-1\"}]}]
```

Comment: You should probably post the entire string instead of cutting if off. We won't be able to figure out if there is anything wrong if we can't see it all.

Comment: Try googling for 'online json validator'.

Comment: You should not have slashes before the quotes. Are you showing the results in a language that automatically escapes them in a string? It seems if those are just regular quotes, then the document validates.

Comment: @Ekaterina, ok, I added the entire string. Thanks for the advice. @500 - Internal Server Error, that's a great idea. With the validator from [link](http://jsonlint.com) I found that all the `\"` in the json string shouldn't be there! They are making the string invalid.

Comment: Your string of JSON is quite valid if all of the quote-escaping is removed. Figure out why slashes are being added...

Comment: That is probably just some PHP logger format. I'm curious for what `$data` and `$guide` are.

Comment: **resolved** guys... thanks to your help. I was suspicious about the quote-escapes `\"` and it is the problem indeed. The data is encoded from the client to the server using a HTML hidden input as the channel and the quote-escapes were added to the string in this process. I fixed this in the server side by calling the PHP function `stripslashes( my_string)` to remove the quote-escapes from the string. @Pumbaa80, this is for a plugin that I am writing; guide a child of a class to this plugin. Thanks for all your inputs, I got to become much more familiar with json encoding now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the JSON other than the fact that the double-quotes that are supposed to delimit string values in the JSON have been encoded as if they were double-quotes **within** a JSON string.

For example:

```
\"instructions\":
```

Should be simply:

```
"instructions":
```

To illustrate how double-quote escaping is intended to work in JSON, consider encoding an object with a single item named **height** with the string value **6'2"**:

```
height: 6'2"
```

Encoded in JSON this would be:

```
{ "height": "6'2\"" }
```

The JSON strings are delimited with double-quotes.  The double-quote internal to the string value itself is then escaped using the backslash character.

Supplementary to this of course is how you encode your string for your given source code language.

If you are using a literal string in your source which is itself double-quote delimited or places special interpretation on '\' then you must adopt the conventions required by the source language in encoding your literals.

Again, by way of an example, consider how the above string would be represented in two different languages:

```
// C# 
s = "{ \"height\": \"6'2\\\"\" }";

// Delphi
s := '{ "height": "6''2\"" }';
```

In C# since '\' marks an escaped character then the '\' in the JSON must itself be escaped.  The double quote characters also need to be escaped since C# string literals are also double-quote delimited.

In Delphi, string literals are single quote delimited, so there is no need to escape the double-quotes, but the *single-quote* within the string must be.  In Delphi this involves only doubling the single quote sequence and there is no need to escape the '\' or '"' characters at all.

Hopefully this will help you understand any mistakes that you may be making in the representation of your JSON strings.

Comment: I see the deltics.JSON connection here.